# Can someone help me name this molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds

[image]

I'm having a hard time deciphering it's IUPAC name like I have 4-butanoxy and 3-propanoxy so far, but how do you put it all together with the double-bonded oxygen?

Thank you and really sorry for the trivial question here.

Comment: This is an acid derivative. Try to identify the acid first.

Answer (score 4):

The motif in the center is *carbonic acid*, hence your compound is *a [carbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonate)* as for instance [dimethyl carbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimethyl_carbonate). (Perhaps the [BOC group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tert-Butyloxycarbonyl_protecting_group) is known to you as a protection of amines, too.)

To the left of the acid you have a butyl rest, to the right an ethyl.  You sort them alphabetically, and hence name the compound butyl ethyl carbonate, [CAS 30714-78-4](https://commonchemistry.cas.org/detail?cas_rn=30714-78-4).

Comment: The CAS name list also allows ethyl butyl carbonate, without the alphabetical sorting.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was really helpful :DD

Comment: @OscarLanzi Perhaps equally allowed (as on the CAS site itself), true. On the other hand, a methyl and an ethyl group on atom 3 of a pentane - this is (preferred?) as 3-ethyl-3-methyl-pentane.  The brief [4-page abstract](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/pac-2019-0104/downloadAsset/suppl/j_pac-2019-0104_suppl.pdf) of the Red Book names MEK as as ethyl methyl ketone, too (page 4, right hand column).

Comment: @idontknowhowtocode The Red Book (and other material about chemical nomenclature) is compiled in the [resources page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry/155812#155812).